# UITextField on UIScrollView (iOS 8.x only)

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8, uitextfield, autolayout

I have a view which is a subclass of `UIScrollView` and `UITextField` is on the `UIScrollView`. I'll refer the subclass of `UIScrollView` as 'CUScrollView'.

The purpose of `CUScrollView` is when user input a text, a button which has a title of the text will be added on the `CUScrollView`. The Offset of `UITextField` will be move at the right of the last added button.

[image]

This is how the `CUScrollView` look like.

Below iOS 8.x, it works perfectly; However it doesn't on iOS 8.x.

When the `UITextField` resigned first responder, the `CUScrollView`'s contentSize is reset to `CUScrollView`'s frame width.

I finally found a work around. I overrided the `setContentSize:` and set the contentSize to whatever I want.

Is it a bug? or some kind of auto layout mistake?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't mix auto layout with setting Frame's manually. If you perform like that then it will be the mistake in your autlayout.

Comment: I tried both auto layout only and frame only. Both not worked. I'm suspicious of AutoLayout; However it worked on iOS 7.